# What will happened If I had used already MYSQL_* functions in my project

Tags: php, mysql

I was not aware of `PDO` or `MYSQLi` functions before developing the project in PHP (Version 5.5) and MYSQL.

But now the project is almost completed but yet to launch the software.

If I launch the project, what problems will I face?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that as soon as it's launched on any server running PHP version 7 or on an older version of PHP where whoever is in charge of the server setup has disabled the mysql_* extension your site will be instantly broken.

Get it migrated over to either the mysqli_* extension or PDO ASAP! Whichever of them two you use **ALWAYS** use prepared statements when sending any variables to the MySQL server, having first made sure to **validate** any user submitted data.

The golden rule is to **NEVER EVER** trust **ANY** user submitted data, no matter how well you trust the users.